# how to get parent $scope object inside directives when different controllers are used?

Tags: angularjs

Please point me out what's going wrong here. am used different third party controller which cannot be made as service. So i used that controller in my directive. When i click on the element in directive, i cant get the parent $scope. what is the issue here.

my

```
--profile.html--- directive template

<div ng-controller="commonCtrl"> userData: {{allData }}
    <a ng-click="printData();">click here</a>
</div>

angular.module('app.core')
.directive('profilePage', DirectiveFunction1 )
.controller('ProfileCtrl', ControllerFunction);

function DirectiveFunction1 (config,service) { 
     var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {}
     }
    return directive;
}

ControllerFunction.$inject = ['$scope', 'config'];

/* @ngInject */
function ControllerFunction($scope, config) {
       $scope.printData = function(){
      // data is not coming here - whats going wrong here
        console.log($scope.allData);
}
}
```

and in different file i have some third party controller like this.

```
angular.module('app.core')
.controller('commonCtrl', commonController);

commonController.$inject = ['$scope']

function commonController($scope){
  $scope.allData = "{user":userDetails}"
}
```

my profile.html is like which is the template of directive.

Comment: can you show your complete html page for this?

Comment: Complete html for which one ?